# Sharing links from website to messenger: is the app_id parameter required?

Tags: html, facebook, share, facebook-messenger

I want to implement social sharing buttons for my website. One of them should be for the facebook messenger.

I've searched everywhere to see if the `app_id` prop in the url params is required or optional. Here is the example from the official documentation:

`<a href=”fb-messenger://share/?link= https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fsharing%2Freference%2Fsend-dialog&app_id=123456789”>Send In Messenger</a>`

The official documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web/) doesn't say anything on the topic so I decided to ask this question here.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually Facebook adds **(optional)** to the parameters that are optional check below

[image]

But keep in mind:

> Starting August 15, 2019, updated versions of the Messenger app will no longer support Share to Messenger SDK. Businesses and developers might need to make modifications to their app to trigger native OS sharing. People will be able to share content to Messenger using the native sharing features that is built into their devices